# Is it possible to utilize Recursive CTE in this example?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, recursive-cte

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTable
create table #MyTable (PolNo varchar(50), ControlNo int, PrevControlNo int, Premim money)
insert into #MyTable values ('Policy-00', 5000, NULL, 1000),
                            ('Policy-01', 6000, 5000, 3200),
                            ('Policy-02', 7000, 6000, 4500),
                            ('Policy-03', 8000, 7000, 3800)
select * from #MyTable
```

**Raw output looks like this:**

[image: ![PolNo ControlNo PrevControlNo Premim Policy-00 5000 NULL 1000.00 Policy-01 6000 5000 3200.00 Policy-02 7000 6000 4500.00 Policy-03 8000 7000 3800.00]

---

**Using the recursive CTE is it possible to get the result like below?**

[image]

I tried something like this, but it basically gives me the same result:

```
;with cte as (
select m.PolNo, m.ControlNo, PrevControlNo, 1 as lvl
from #MyTable m
union all 
select c.PolNo, c.ControlNo, c.PrevControlNo, c.lvl+1
from cte c
inner join #MyTable m ON m.ControlNo = c.PrevControlNo
where c.PrevControlNo IS  NULL
) 
select cte.PolNo,  ControlNo, PrevControlNo
from cte
```

Comment: How are you managing the recursion? In your expected output, Policy-03 (control 8000) has a previous control of 7000, which itself has a previous control of 6000, etc. If you are only worried about the 1 direct previous control, then you can do a simple self join without a CTE.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's right.  I guess I overcomplicated everything. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` is enough for single level:

```
SELECT *
FROM #MyTable m1
LEFT JOIN #MyTable m2
  ON m2.ControlNo = m1.PrevControlNo;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bef1c6f1a10ec9503ef788090c2dc636)**